# Space efficient minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, space-complexity, kruskals-algorithm, prims-algorithm

I've come across a task that basically asks you to find MST of the given graph in which all the vertices are connected. I tried using Kruskal's algorithm but I soon figured out that the space bound is too tight for one to store all the edges by a mebibyte, so I also gave up on Prim's and Boruvka's algorithm. Is there a way to implement any of these algorithms (or any other MST algorithm) with space complexity better than O(E) which is in this case O(V^2)?

Comment: how would you know the weigth of each edge without storing them all

Comment: Don't know, that's why I'm asking whether there exists a way to do so or maybe another way to find a MST.

Comment: Maybe post your code to find space optimizations

Comment: I believe @juvian has a valid point. I believe the space requirements of the task excludes the storage cost of the graph. (i.e. adjacency list) If it didn't, there is no way of you to represent the graph given as input. If I am correct, and the question excludes the cost of storing the adjacency list, then Prim's algorithm could do the trick for you so long as you store a single element within the priority queue for each vertex. (i.e. if you use a set as opposed to a priority queue) If you indeed use a set in Prim's algorithm, then the set would contain at most O(V) elements.

Comment: juvian is right. You can't construct the MST without knowing the weights, and this unavoidably costs O(V²) space. But maybe in your case the weights can be computed instead of stored ?

Answer (score 0):

For the case where you can compute the weights using a function w(i,j) you can compute a minimum spanning tree in space O(n) instead of O(n^2) using Prim's algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Classic_algorithms).

At each stage maintain the set T of nodes in the tree, and for each node not in the tree maintain the least distance from that node to any node in the tree.

At the start T is node 0 and for each other node you compute the least distance from node 0 to that node.

At each stage pick the node not in the tree with least distance. Now compute the distance from that node to all other nodes not in the tree. If that is less than their current least distance update that least distance.

Storage cost is O(n) to maintain T and O(n) to maintain for each node not in the tree a note of the least distance from the tree to that node.